I replaced < with &#60, but it renders as &lt
I'm using vanilla JavaScript to help me prepare some text for injection into an HTML page.
The script takes a bunch of text strings (words and part-words), adds links around each one, and puts them in a grid.
Some of these strings are surrounded by greater-than/less-than symbols:  <..>
So that these show up in the HTML page (and aren't interpreted as HTML tags), I've replaced them in the old string (s) into the new string (new_s) (or, specifically in the innerHTML of the rendered element) using:
new_s.innerHTML = s.replaceAll("<","&#60;").replaceAll(">","&#62;");

Works fine.
In the links that wrap around this text, text strings that were <somestring> have links that are -somestring-, so I want to replace the newly replaced < and > with -.
Additionally, I want this in a standalone function so that a user can click on a preview word grid later to remove or add-back a link before injection.
I have:
lnk = new_s.innerHTML.replaceAll("&#60;","-").replaceAll("&#62;","-");

And then I put that lnk into <a> tags. But I found that this isn't working (minimally in Firefox), because once < is replaced with &#60;, it renders as &lt;.
I solved this with work-arounds, but I'm confused as to why this is happening. I didn't see other Stack Overflow post on this, and web searches just told me how to replace < with &lt or &#60.
Does anyone have an insight? Are there things I should to to avoid issues in the future? Is this universal behavior across browsers?
I have solved this with a duplicate line:
lnk = new_s.innerHTML;
lnk = lnk.replaceAll("&#60;","-").replaceAll("&#62;","-");
lnk = lnk.replaceAll("&lt;","-").replaceAll("&gt;","-");

However, I was expecting that using a character code replacement would keep that character code stable instead of switching it to an alias.

&#60 is < - so when it renders, it puts in the <.   When you use .innerHTML, you are extracting the rendered HTML - in most cases, that's what you provided, but not always.  eg if you pass in illegal HTML, the browser will change it to make it allowed (off topic, but an example seen on SO is a <form> tag inside a <tr> - it gets moved to outside the table.  So the rendered DOM is not identical to the source HTML.

The two are merely two ways to represent the same character. Either by the character code or by the canonical name. However, once given to innerHTML THE CONTENT IS NOT PRESEVED AS-IS. Never rely on innerHTML to be what you set it to - it's a setter, so it'd evaluate the text you've given it. It evidently decides to use a single canonical name for the character. It can also do other changes to your code.

One very common issue is el.innerHTML += "<div>"; el.innerHTML += "content"; el.innerHTML += "</div>" - since it's separate sets, you're not filling up one string. You're giving some HTML first to the browser which it will do its best guess to fix and then you'll add some content, then the third set is still some invalid HTML that the browser with handle somehow.

Can you share this as a [mre] such that others can inspect the problem further, and possibly provide other solutions?

Thank you for these comments @fdomn-m !
This is exactly the information that I was looking for. I figured there must be a rendering stage, but wasn't sure what was happening.

And also thank you @VLAZ !
Same as other comment -- This is exactly the information that I was looking for. I figured there must be a rendering stage, but wasn't sure what was happening.

If you really need to take this approach, there's not even a need to escape anything.
Just use new_s.innerText = '<example>';.


const myText = "<example>";

new_s.innerText = myText;
<div id="new_s"></div>



If you wish to extract and/or make links, you can use another approach:


// Matches: <example>
const shortUrl = /<([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)>/g;

// Matches: https://www.domain.url
const fullUrl = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;

// The function to parse the links:
const parseLinks = myString =>
{
  var myResult = String(myString);
  var myReplacements = {};
  
  const shortMatches = myResult.matchAll(shortUrl);
  const fullMatches = myResult.matchAll(fullUrl);
  
  for ( const [ fullMatch ] of fullMatches )
  {
    const newAnchor = document.createElement('a');
    
    newAnchor.href = fullMatch;
    newAnchor.innerText = fullMatch;
    
    myReplacements[fullMatch] = newAnchor.outerHTML;
  }
  
  for ( const [ shortMatch ] of shortMatches )
  {
    const textContent = shortMatch.substring(1, shortMatch.length -1);
    const newAnchor = document.createElement('a');
    
    newAnchor.href = textContent;
    newAnchor.innerText = textContent;
    
    if ( ! Reflect.has(myReplacements, textContent) )
    {
      myReplacements[shortMatch] = newAnchor.outerHTML;
    }
  }
  
  // Replacements happen here:
  for ( const myReplacement in myReplacements )
  {
    myResult = myResult.replaceAll(myReplacement, myReplacements[myReplacement]);
  }
  
  return myResult;
}

// Examples

const myText1 = 'The first example: </simple/Relative/Link>';
const myText2 = 'The second example: https://www.stackoverflow.com';
const myText3 = 'The third example: <https://www.stackoverflow.com>';

const myParsed1 = parseLinks(myText1);
const myParsed2 = parseLinks(myText2);
const myParsed3 = parseLinks(myText3);

document.body.innerHTML += myParsed1 + '<br/>';
document.body.innerHTML += myParsed2 + '<br/>';
document.body.innerHTML += myParsed3 + '<br/>';



NOTE: The pattern <some-link> causes tags to be parsed into links. Avoid passing HTML to parseLinks().
